# Cannot get rails app deployed on heroku because of: "failed to detect app matching no buildpack"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app on heroku. But am getting the follow error when deploying

```
MHC-MBP:attr_reader mohun$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 855 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 0), reused 10 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Failed to detect app matching no buildpack
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to murmuring-hamlet-70215.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/murmuring-hamlet-70215.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/murmuring-hamlet-70215.git'
```

Here is my folder structure while im in the root rails app directory.

```
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── README.md
├── README2.md
├── Rakefile
├── app
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── config
│   │   │   └── manifest.js
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   ├── book25.png
│   │   │   ├── book26.png
│   │   │   ├── book27.png
│   │   │   ├── book28.png
│   │   │   ├── book29.png
│   │   │   ├── book30.png
│   │   │   ├── book31.png
│   │   │   ├── book32.png
│   │   │   ├── book33.png
│   │   │   ├── book34.png
│   │   │   ├── book35.png
│   │   │   ├── book36.png
│   │   │   ├── book37.png
│   │   │   ├── book38.png
│   │   │   ├── book39.png
│   │   │   ├── book40.png
│   │   │   ├── book41.png
│   │   │   ├── book42.png
│   │   │   ├── book43.png
│   │   │   ├── book44.png
│   │   │   ├── book45.png
│   │   │   ├── book46.png
│   │   │   └── emptyshelf.png
│   │   ├── javascripts
│   │   │   ├── application.js
│   │   │   ├── books.coffee
│   │   │   ├── cable.js
│   │   │   ├── channels
│   │   │   ├── home.coffee
│   │   │   ├── search.coffee
│   │   │   └── users.coffee
│   │   └── stylesheets
│   │       ├── application.css
│   │       ├── books.scss
│   │       ├── home.scss
│   │       ├── search.scss
│   │       └── users.scss
│   ├── channels
│   │   └── application_cable
│   │       ├── channel.rb
│   │       └── connection.rb
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── application_controller.rb
│   │   ├── books_controller.rb
│   │   ├── concerns
│   │   ├── home_controller.rb
│   │   ├── search_controller.rb
│   │   ├── users
│   │   │   ├── confirmations_controller.rb
│   │   │   ├── omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb
│   │   │   ├── passwords_controller.rb
│   │   │   ├── registrations_controller.rb
│   │   │   ├── sessions_controller.rb
│   │   │   └── unlocks_controller.rb
│   │   └── users_controller.rb
│   ├── helpers
│   │   ├── application_helper.rb
│   │   ├── books_helper.rb
│   │   ├── home_helper.rb
│   │   ├── search_helper.rb
│   │   └── users_helper.rb
│   ├── jobs
│   │   └── application_job.rb
│   ├── mailers
│   │   ├── application_mailer.rb
│   │   └── user_mailer.rb
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── application_record.rb
│   │   ├── book.rb
│   │   ├── concerns
│   │   ├── relation.rb
│   │   └── user.rb
│   └── views
│       ├── books
│       │   ├── index.html.erb
│       │   ├── new.html.erb
│       │   ├── profile.html.erb
│       │   ├── search.html.erb
│       │   └── show.html.erb
│       ├── devise
│       │   ├── confirmations
│       │   │   └── new.html.erb
│       │   ├── mailer
│       │   │   ├── confirmation_instructions.html.erb
│       │   │   ├── email_changed.html.erb
│       │   │   ├── password_change.html.erb
│       │   │   ├── reset_password_instructions.html.erb
│       │   │   └── unlock_instructions.html.erb
│       │   ├── passwords
│       │   │   ├── edit.html.erb
│       │   │   └── new.html.erb
│       │   ├── registrations
│       │   │   ├── edit.html.erb
│       │   │   └── new.html.erb
│       │   ├── sessions
│       │   │   └── new.html.erb
│       │   ├── shared
│       │   │   └── _links.html.erb
│       │   └── unlocks
│       │       └── new.html.erb
│       ├── home
│       │   └── index.html.erb
│       ├── layouts
│       │   ├── _footer.html.erb
│       │   ├── _header.html.erb
│       │   ├── application.html.erb
│       │   ├── mailer.html.erb
│       │   └── mailer.text.erb
│       └── user_mailer
│           ├── book_trade.html.erb
│           ├── book_trade.text.erb
│           ├── spam.html.erb
│           ├── spam.text.erb
│           ├── welcome_send.html.erb
│           └── welcome_send.text.erb
├── bin
│   ├── bundle
│   ├── rails
│   ├── rake
│   ├── setup
│   ├── spring
│   └── update
├── config
│   ├── application.rb
│   ├── boot.rb
│   ├── cable.yml
│   ├── database.yml
│   ├── environment.rb
│   ├── environments
│   │   ├── development.rb
│   │   ├── production.rb
│   │   └── test.rb
│   ├── initializers
│   │   ├── application_controller_renderer.rb
│   │   ├── assets.rb
│   │   ├── backtrace_silencers.rb
│   │   ├── cookies_serializer.rb
│   │   ├── devise.rb
│   │   ├── filter_parameter_logging.rb
│   │   ├── inflections.rb
│   │   ├── mime_types.rb
│   │   ├── new_framework_defaults.rb
│   │   ├── session_store.rb
│   │   └── wrap_parameters.rb
│   ├── locales
│   │   ├── devise.en.yml
│   │   └── en.yml
│   ├── puma.rb
│   ├── routes.rb
│   ├── secrets.yml
│   └── spring.rb
├── config.ru
├── db
│   ├── migrate
│   │   ├── 20170426180200_devise_create_users.rb
│   │   ├── 20170426180730_add_username_to_users.rb
│   │   ├── 20170426181324_add_other_columns_to_users.rb
│   │   ├── 20170426182016_create_books.rb
│   │   ├── 20170430191321_add_books_status_column.rb
│   │   ├── 20170502183642_create_relations.rb
│   │   └── 20170502224222_add_foreign_keys_to_relations.rb
│   ├── schema.rb
│   └── seeds.rb
├── lib
│   ├── assets
│   └── tasks
├── log
├── master
├── public
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── 422.html
│   ├── 500.html
│   ├── apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
│   ├── apple-touch-icon.png
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── robots.txt
├── readme_books.md
├── test
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── books_controller_test.rb
│   │   ├── home_controller_test.rb
│   │   ├── search_controller_test.rb
│   │   └── users_controller_test.rb
│   ├── fixtures
│   │   ├── books.yml
│   │   ├── files
│   │   ├── relations.yml
│   │   └── users.yml
│   ├── helpers
│   ├── integration
│   ├── mailers
│   │   ├── previews
│   │   │   └── user_mailer_preview.rb
│   │   └── user_mailer_test.rb
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── book_test.rb
│   │   ├── relation_test.rb
│   │   └── user_test.rb
│   └── test_helper.rb
├── test.txt
└── vendor
    └── assets
        ├── javascripts
        └── stylesheets
```

I'm new to ruby and heroku so if you could word any answers you have in simple terms, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to detect app matching no buildpack

Heroku is unable to detect which language it is

Adding this in `Gemfile` will fix the issue

```
ruby '2.4'
```

Or you can set the buildpack manually

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
```